# Is there a way to run a function for each email in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary, python-requests

I am writing a script to autofill and submit a form. It can do that fine but I have to change the email in the payload dictionary for every email I want to enter. Is there anyway that I can have a dictionary or a list with all my emails and then loop the entering code to autofill an email from that list and submit until all the emails are entered?
Here is my code.

```
import requests


payload = { # data I need to send to their servers to submit the form
    'g': 'UhQRUE',
    '$fields':'$source,$email,$consent_method,$consent_form_id,$consent_form_version,services',
    '$list_fields': '',
    '$timezone_offset':'-5',
    '$source':'Gift Card Giveaway Form',
    '$email':"sampleemail@gmail.com",
    '$consent_method': "Klaviyo Form",
    '$consent_form_id': 'WbvfNT',
    '$consent_form_version': '1842792',
    'services': '{"shopify":{"source":"form"}}',

}

s = requests.post("https://a.klaviyo.com/ajax/subscriptions/subscribe", data=payload)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work fine, adding, obviusly, a condition to exit the loop as needed:

```
import requests

mails = ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"]

payload = { # data I need to send to their servers to submit the form
    'g': 'UhQRUE',
    '$fields':'$source,$email,$consent_method,$consent_form_id,$consent_form_version,services',
    '$list_fields': '',
    '$timezone_offset':'-5',
    '$source':'Gift Card Giveaway Form',
    '$email':"sampleemail@gmail.com",
    '$consent_method': "Klaviyo Form",
    '$consent_form_id': 'WbvfNT',
    '$consent_form_version': '1842792',
    'services': '{"shopify":{"source":"form"}}',
}

for mail in mails:
    payload['$email'] = mail
    s = requests.post("https://a.klaviyo.com/ajax/subscriptions/subscribe", data=payload)
```